# executeBatch in ERC-4337

Tags: solidity, erc-4337, account-abstraction

I have a question regarding executeBatch
here is the code block

```
 /**
     * execute a transaction (called directly from owner, or by entryPoint)
     */
    function execute(
        address dest,
        uint256 value,
        bytes calldata func
    ) external {
        _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
        _call(dest, value, func);
    }

    /**
     * execute a sequence of transactions
     */
    function executeBatch(
        address[] calldata dest,
        bytes[] calldata func
    ) external {
        _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
        require(dest.length == func.length, "wrong array lengths");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < dest.length; i++) {
            _call(dest[i], 0, func[i]);
        }
    }
```

Why is there no parameter `uint256[] calldata value` in executeBatch?

Answer (score 0):

I think they might have not updated it . But in the latest code its there

```
`function executeBatch(address[] calldata dest, uint256[] calldata value, bytes[] calldata func) external {
    _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
    require(dest.length == func.length && (value.length == 0 || value.length == func.length), "wrong array lengths");
    if (value.length == 0)`
```